# Null pointer, touch Event on two maps

Tags: touch

I got a big problem
I have to map view for me a transferring back to point I touch on the phone
and I don't use ant Itemizedovelay, just map,overlay an touchevent
one is worked, but the other one give me these logcat and just crachdown

this is really weird, does anyone know or meet up this problem?

-thanks
-Dennnis

here's the logcat

```
> Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
$ThisMapOverlay1.onTouchEvent(Favoritepoint.java:222)
com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTouchEvent(OverlayBundle.java:63)
com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:625)
android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:852)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.    java:1659)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:  1643)
android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```